# Getting the value of a specific input that is dynamically added from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of a specific input on an `onclick` event

This function retrieves all the data from my back-end

Javascript

```
function getProjects() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      functionToCall: 'project',
    },
    url: 'http://localhost/WBS/php/api/requests/get.php',
    success: (response) => {
      $.each(response, function () {
        $.each(this, function (index, value) {
          $('#project-body').append(
            `
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control projectid" type="hidden" name="projectid[]" value="${value.projectid}">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control projectName" type="text" name="projectName[]" value="${value.title}">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control description" type="text" name="description[]" value="${value.description}">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control estimatedTime" type="text" name="estimatedTime[]" value="${value.Estimated_time}">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input class="form-control actualTime" type="text" name="actualTime[]" value="${value.Actual_time}">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="btn btn-info addTask" href="Overview.html?id=${value.projectid}" role="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Add task
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button value="${value.projectid}" type="button" name="deleteProject" class="btn btn-danger deleteProject">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"> </i> Delete project
                  </button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            `
          );
        });
      });
    },
    error: () => {
      console.error('Something went wrong with the getProjects function');
    },
  });
}
```

I would like to get the value of this specific input

```
<td>
    <input class="form-control projectid" type="hidden" name="projectid[]" value="${value.projectid}">
</td>
```

I tried using this

```js
  $(document).on('click', '.btn.btn-danger.deleteProject', () => {
    let id = $(this).find('tr').closest('.form-control.projectid');
    deleteProject(id); // this is an ajax call that deletes a project with said ID
  });
```

But console.logging this returns undefined on all button clicks, i tried hardcoding it

```js
  $(document).on('click', '.btn.btn-danger.deleteProject', () => {
    let id = $('.btn.btn-danger.deleteProject').val();
    deleteProject(id);
  });
```

And this returns a ID, the problem being it only ever returns the first ID all the time.

My question being, how do I get said input value from a onclick event?

Comment: so you call the api get the data and build the html when you click on a button, after that can you explain little more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest` tests the element itself and its `ancestors` for matching the selector.

What you need to do is: find closest `tr` to the button clicked and then inside of that `tr` find the input, so something like this:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.btn.btn-danger.deleteProject', function() {
    const id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.form-control.projectid').val();
    deleteProject(id);
  });
```

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the needed id was already stored in the `value` attribute of the clicked button, so you could simply do `const id = $(this).val();`

Comment: Hey, I tried doing it with just `const id = $(this).val()` but console.log  but this gives an error of `TypeError: can't access property "toLowerCase", elem.nodeName is undefined` update: using `const id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.form-control.projectid').val();
`  returns undefined in the console log

Comment: Yes, there's a mistake in my answer, it's using an arrow function and therefore `this` is not pointing to the node on which the event was triggered. You can make it work by changing the arrow function to a regular function like this (also edited my answer): 

$(document).on('click', '.btn.btn-danger.deleteProject', function() {
  // code
});

Comment: Yup that seems to fix it, goddamn javascript and it's weird quirks. Thank you !